# PCL17 Does not compile

Tags: pcl, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to rosmake pcl17 or pcl17_ros i get the following error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsensor_msgs

I have the sensor_msgs package.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65163/pcl17-does-not-compile/) by [mdedonato](https://answers.ros.org/users/4929/mdedonato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-06-17**:
We need more information. Can you describe what you did step by step? Do you use fuerte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not knowing what version of ROS you are using or seeing the full error message, this problem might already be solved here in this answer: [How do I use pcl 1.7 with groovy?](http://answers.ros.org/question/62979/how-do-i-use-pcl-17-with-groovy/).

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-06-15**:
I've just compiled this one `git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git -b groovy-unstable-devel`. You have to change pcl-1.6 to pcl-1.7 in .//pcl/doc/tutorials/content/walkthrough.rst to successfully build other packages that depend on pcl.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-06-16**:
Do you have installed sensor_msgs? On Ubuntu you can do this with "apt-get install ros-groovy-common-msgs".

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-06-17**:
BTW after I compiled PCL, rosbuild cannot compile costmap2d anymore, it cannot find pcl.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-06-17**:
@Art: you should use catkin

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-06-17**:
I do use catkin to build catkin packages including pcl. However, rosbuild packages also uses catkin packages.  I don't know why when  I build pcl-1.7, costmap2d does not find it. I don't have the log now,  I rolled back to pcl-1.6 now. Actually, let me try to build pcl-1.7 in overlay workspace.